# html to pdf fit table on A4

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, html-pdf

im currently using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) which takes my table data and turns it into an pdf.

My problem is that the table content is overlapping the required `A4` papersize in such way that there is 2 columns totally missing in the pdf, when ever i change the 
`format` to `A3` it fits and works.

I need it for `A4` to fit. Any ideas ?

```js
const dlPdfResult = (result) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    optionsType = {
      format: 'A4',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      paginationOffset: 0,
      header: {
        'height': '10mm',
        'contents': `<div style=' font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 11px; text-align: left;  width: 842px; overflow: hidden;'><div style='width: 10%; float:left;'></div><div style='width: 40%; float:left;padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px;'>Port2Port exports</div><div style='width: 40%; float:left; text-align: right;'>Logo</div><div style='width: 10%; float:left;'></div>`
      },
      footer: {
        'height': '10mm',
        'contents': {
          first: '1',
          2: '2',
          default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>',
          last: 'Last Page'
        },
        type: 'pdf', // allowed file types: png, jpeg, pdf
        quality: '75'
      }
    }
    tableForm = tableify(result)

    pdf.create(tableForm, optionsType).toFile('./test.pdf', function (err, res) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(res)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment my only fix is to replace the table results i get and adding styles to that using `mm` and giving it `max-width`.

just one example would be:

```
tableForm = tableify(result)

strip = tableForm.replace(/<td/g, `<td style='max-width: 5mm;border: 1px solid #000;overflow: hidden;word-wrap: break-word;'`)
```

I did this for all the `td`and all the `th`.

so my next replace looked like:

```
var addStyleSpacingThString = strip.replace(/<th class="string">/g, `<th class='string' style='max-width: 5mm;text-align: left;'>`)
```

This is working an fitting all my content the last thing i want to mention is that my table itself has a width of 100%.

`<table style=' width: 100%; heigth: auto;font-size: 11px;font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; border-collapse: collapse;'>`

Comment: This was a quick fix, i am looking for some better way to resolve this without adding styles to the `td` or `th`

Comment: Did you find a fix?